# understanding process flow for $window.onNotificationGCM

Tags: phonegap-pushplugin

Looking at this code, I'm wondering what triggers `onNotificationGCM`? It is triggered when the app is registered but when does it get triggered again, say, when when I want to push a message to the user? I have a chat app that I'd like to push a message when chats come in. So I understand that I register the device but then this code needs to run again, I assume, with the new event. I just need understand part flow and part code.

```
// handle GCM notifications for Android
$window.onNotificationGCM = function (event) {
switch (event.event) {
  case 'registered':
    if (event.regid.length > 0) {
      // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
      // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
      var device_token = event.regid;
      RequestsService.register(device_token).then(function(response){
          alert('registered!');
        });
      //send device reg id to server

    }
    break;

  case 'message':
      // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
      // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
      if (event.foreground) {
            console.log('INLINE NOTIFICATION');
            var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + event.soundname);
            my_media.play();
      } else {
        if (event.coldstart) {
            console.log('COLDSTART NOTIFICATION');
        } else {
            console.log('BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION');
        }
      }

      navigator.notification.alert(event.payload.message);
      console.log('MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + event.payload.message);
      //Only works for GCM
      console.log('MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + event.payload.msgcnt);
      //Only works on Amazon Fire OS
      console.log('MESSAGE -> TIME: ' + event.payload.timeStamp);
      break;

  case 'error':
      console.log('ERROR -> MSG:' + event.msg);
      break;

  default:
      console.log('EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is');
      break;
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example:

```
case 'message':
    /*
    if (e.foreground) {
    window.alert("Message recieved");
    }
    else {
    if (e.coldstart) {
    window.alert("Coldstart Notification");
    } else {
    window.alert("Background Notification");
    }
    }
    window.alert("Notification message: " + e.payload.message
               + "\n\n Time: " + e.payload.conversation);
    */

    var data = e.payload;
    if (data.conversation){
        window.history.replaceState(null, '', '#/chats/');
        ProjectName.conversation.load(data.conversation);
    }
    if (data.product){
        window.history.replaceState(null, '', '#/product/' + data.product);
    }
    break;
case 'error':
    // window.alert("Notification error: " + e.msg);
    break;
default:
    // window.alert("Notification - Unknown event");
    break;
}
```

The `e.payload` contains all data that you send to your application, including `message`. You can access your other variables in `case 'message'`

Comment: Ok, that I think I get. I'm just curious if this "ecb":"window.onNotificationGCM" gets called on-demand say someplace downstream in my app which contains the payload. I wrote a node api using node-gcm which has a register/ route and would replace your local storage but that also has a /push route. There i construct the message I want to send. I'm assuming, once a call to push is complete, it will, somehow, trigger "ecb":"window.onNotificationGCM and send the payload I've constructed there. Does this seem correct? Thanks for the example

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. :)

Comment: Np problem. For one reason or another, ecb wasn't being fired from my server after I created the payload. As it turns out, there was something wrong with the key i created in Google. I'd never built one of these things before and didn't know if I was thinking about it wrong. Seems to be working well now. Thanks